# Is there a solution for google maps API v3 to make marker clusters exists?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a solution for this? I want something like [this post](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html) but all I can find is for google maps v2 API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a V3 version of MarkerClusterer which supports maps v3 API.

http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

Answer (score 0):

There's a Sourceforge library called Fluster you can use for v3: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fluster/

http://blog.fusonic.net/2009/12/clustering-for-google-maps-v3-with-fluster2/